# Select rows in the next page in ag-grid

Tags: angular, select, ag-grid

I am developing a table in ag-grid using Angular2. I have a table that contains 3 pages. I have a dropdown menu that can select all the rows in the current page, but i also want a function that can select all the rows in the table (so in the next 2 pages as well).

So far i have found this function, but this selects only the rows in the current page.

```
  gridOptions.api.forEachNode( function (node) {
        node.setSelected(true);
});
```

I also have unique id's of the rows. The following code doesn't work either:

```
  gridOptions.api.forEachNode( function (node) {
        if(node.data.id === 25) {
        node.setSelected(true);
       }
});
```

The id *25* is in the second page. This code works if i am on the second page.

Is there a way to achieve what i want in ag-grid?

Comment: gridOptions.api.selectAll() ?

Comment: this function selects the rows in the current page

Comment: What methods are available once you get the row model - api.getModel()? Seems like a place to get the information about the original rows..

Comment: i'm sorry,  but there are aren't methods for selecting all the rows.

Comment: the `gridOptions.api `points to the grid api in your current page. To select row in the other grid, you need to reference the gridAPI for the other grids.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I have to refer to the gridAPI for the other grids.